# Find and print key which having more than one value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictVal={'1':'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_2.png,1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_4.png',
'2' :'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_3.png','0': '1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_1.png'}
```

I want to print that which key in the dictionary having more than one value, I searched but looking for a better understanding way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with it (with the condition than , is only used to seperate values AND NOT in the values):

```
dictVal={'1':'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_2.png,1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_4.png',
'2' :'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_3.png','0': '1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_1.png',
'3':'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_2.png,1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_4.png'}

for k,v in dictVal.items():
    if len(v.split(','))>1:
        print(k)
```

Comment: Could just check if the string contains comma `if ',' in v:`

Answer (score 1):

Use this , You need to iterate over `dictVal` to find out the keys having more than one value

```
res = []

dictVal={'1':'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_2.png,1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_4.png',
'2' :'1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_3.png','0': '1_org_85_3103_85_4133_467_3103_467_4133_1.png'}

for key in dictVal:
    split_val = dictVal[key].split(",")
    if len(split_val) > 1:
       res += [key]
```

`res` will contain all the keys which has a contain more than one values

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = [key for key, val in dic.items()  if len(val.split(','))>1 ]
print(keys)
```

Returns a list of keys having more than 1 items.